# FilterWithKeys for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, filter, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

In [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.0/index.html), we're given a lot of higher-order combinators to do practical work. One that's very convenient is the `.filter()` utility - we are given the `Array.filter()` function in ES6, but ramda (and lodash I believe) give us the ability to filter over objects as well. For me, I would like a tool to filter over *both* the keys and the values at the same time.

The `const` keyword in ES6 is a very powerful tool - by using it with arbitrary (non-object) values, we can have a guarantee that the value will never change for the rest of the block (and help us deduce bugs, lots of other very nice gains). The only other practical way to filter keys and values from an object is using `for .. in`, which *forces* you to use a mutable variable:

```
let xs = {...}
for (const k in xs) {
  if (someProperty(k,xs[k])) {
    delete xs[k]
  }
}
```

I argue that using `filterWithKey` would alleviate this issue:

```
const xs = filterWithKey(someProperty, {...})
```

Is there anything like this in a popular javascript library? I haven't seen anything like it in ramda or lodash yet, I'm not sure where else to look. I think this would be a suitable implementation though:

```
function filterWithKey (p,xs) {
  R.toPairs(xs).reduce((acc,x) => {
    const k = x[0]
    const v = x[1]
    return p(k,v) ? acc[k] = v : acc
  })
}
```

It still requires the act of rebuilding the object though. Is there a better solution?

Comment: If you're asking if there's any implementations of a filter function for objects that fitlers **in-place**, there probably isn't, most methods like that returns a new object, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I'm trying to see if there's any more optimizations that could be used in this design - I'm not sure though obviously

Comment: Declaring a variable with `const` whose value is an object does not prevent its properties from being modified. Sealing or freezing the object do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda only recently added the ability to filter objects on their values; until then it natively supported lists, and would otherwise delegate to an object's `filter` method if it existed.  But in [Issue 1429](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1429) it was extended to plain objects as well.

There was a great deal of discussion in that issue about the possibility of supporting a `keys` parameter as well, but eventually it was demonstrated to be too much at odds with other parts of the library.

I just added a section to [Ramda's Cookbook](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Cookbook#filter-an-object-using-keys-as-well-as-values) describing one way to write this function for yourself:

```
const filterWithKeys = (pred, obj) => R.pipe(
  R.toPairs, 
  R.filter(R.apply(pred)), 
  R.fromPairs
)(obj);

filterWithKeys(
  (key, val) => key.length === val, 
  {red: 3, blue: 5, green: 5, yellow: 2}
); //=> {red: 3, green: 5}
```

If you have a more useful short example, I'd love to include it instead.

Like anything in the Ramda world, it does not mutate your input data.  This is really important in functional programming, and I would not be interested in working with a version built that way. In other words, I see this as a feature:

> It still requires the act of rebuilding the object though.